# How to inspect objects in Netbeans debugger and x-debug

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I'm using Netbeans and xdebug with php 5.3 to debug my application and I can't inspect objects properties in the variables panel

only CLASSNAME appears

is there a special setting in netbeans or xdebug ?

any one encountered thi situation?

I'm pretty sure I coudld debug my objects before but I upgraded to php 5.3 and so the php.ini changed, but I copied my xdebug settings over from my old php.ini

any help appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an old Xdebug. CLASSNAME has been removed since version Xdebug 2.1.1 (release March 28th, 2011). Please upgrade to the latest version and the problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried PhP versions 5.3.8 and 5.3.10 and Xdebug versions 2.1.1, 2.1.2 and 2.1.4 as well as running under window XAMP and WAMP servers and remote XDEBUG under Linux (Ubuntu) server and still experience the same problem, values for object variables are generally not shown though some very rare times they do show after flashing many times "Evaluating" under value in the Variables window.